# Calculate average of all values in a specific column of a 2d array

Tags: php, arrays, object, average, array-column

I need to find the average of all `AdjClose` values in my two dimensional array.

I have an array stored in a variable `$data`. It looks like this:

```
["data"]=>
  array(22) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#234 (7) {
      ["Date"]=>
      string(10) "2016-08-31"
      ["Open"]=>
      string(9) "767.01001"
      ["High"]=>
      string(10) "769.090027"
      ["Low"]=>
      string(10) "765.380005"
      ["Close"]=>
      string(10) "767.049988"
      ["Volume"]=>
      string(7) "1247400"
      ["AdjClose"]=>
      string(10) "767.049988"
    }
    [1]=>
    object(stdClass)#240 (7) {
      ["Date"]=>
      string(10) "2016-08-30"
      ["Open"]=>
      string(10) "769.330017"
      ["High"]=>
      string(10) "774.466003"
      ["Low"]=>
      string(10) "766.840027"
      ["Close"]=>
      string(10) "769.090027"
      ["Volume"]=>
      string(7) "1127100"
      ["AdjClose"]=>
      string(10) "769.090027"
    }
```

It has around 22 entries and I want to iterate through every  ["AdjClose"] and calculate the average of these numbers.

From what I understand, I should write something like:
`if(@$data->data->AdjClose)` but this is where my problems begin.

Can someone explain to me please how to iterate through the objects/rows access and store the AdjClose values and calculate the average?

Comment: What is your PHP version?

Comment: do you get this data throughh `json_decode()`? if yes then add `true` as a second parameter, so that you can get normal array and then you can use foreach loop to get the desired data easily

Comment: @Anant you can iterate through an array of objects just as easily

Comment: My php version is 5.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example of an iterative solution, since you were asking about how that would work:

```
// initialize sum and total
$sum = 0;
$total = 0;

foreach ($data->data as $obj) {
    if (isset($obj->AdjClose)) {   // verify that the current object has an AdjClose
        $sum += $obj->AdjClose;    // add it to the sum
        $total++;                  // increment the count
    }
}
echo $sum / $total;                // display the average
```

I added the `if (isset($obj->AdjClose)` check because you asked about `if(@$data->data->AdjClose)`. I thought that implied that `AdjClose` might not be present in some of the objects. If that is the case, I wanted to show how to check for it rather than using the error suppression operator (`@`). If you want items without `AdjClose` to be included in the average as zeroes, you can move the `$total++` outside the `if` block.

---

If you have PHP 7, you can also do this using `array_column` (but again, unless you want to include missing `AdjClose` properties in your average as zeroes, only use this if `AdjClose` is defined on all of the objects).

```
$average = array_sum(array_column($data->data, 'AdjClose')) / count($data->data)
```

Answer (score 3):

Arrays are processed using one of the looping structures I suggest `foreach` in this case

```
$cnt = 0;
$tot = 0;
foreach ( $data['data'] as $obj ) {

    $cnt++;
    $tot += (float)$obj->AdjClose;
}

$mean = $tot / $cnt;
echo 'The mean is ' . $mean;
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple code:

```
$total = 0;
foreach($data['data'] as $item) {
    $total += (float)item->AdjClose;
}

$res = $total / count($data['data']);
```